# Unable to create NSDate from string

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code in Playground, and `date` is always nil.

```
let str = "2015-12-07T22:26:37.624Z"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS"
let date = formatter.dateFromString(str)
```

The date string is retrieved from my server, which is always in GMT+0.

Comment: `str` ends in `Z`, while your format doesn't. Add a `Z` to the end of `dateFormat` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the trailing `Z` of the date string

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSZ"
//The Z at the end of your string represents Zulu which is UTC
```

Comment: what does the trailing Z mean

Comment: It is the time zone definition.

Comment: `Z` represents the time zone, without an offset UTC